# make dynamic array in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

How to make a dynamic array in the middle of a program in assembly?
I tried this code and it didn't work

```
.CODE
.DATA
list DWORD <register or memory>DUP(?)
```

Do you know any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You usually don't! You either have to reserve "enough" memory at compile time, or call the OS to allocate more at runtime.

Comment: @BoPersson is exactly right. Depending on OS, you can use the allocation functions, but if you need more memory, I just suggest calling into the C library for malloc. If that is not an option, look into your OS's process break syscall. On Linux, that's `brk`.

Comment: @BoPersson ,I want to make array and if it was full , want to copy it to another array with 2 more size or resize it larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dup` is not NASM or FASM syntax, but MASM; and since you cannot legally use MASM on *nix, `sys_newstat` and `sys_brk` would be out of the question.  So you are targeting Windows?

You would use the `Heap*` memory API functions.  You would use `HeapAlloc` and `HeapReAlloc`.  If you don't mind the CRT dependency, then you could do as Linuxios reccommends and use `malloc`

Comment: how I can use from malloc in MASM ?